# Why is the following code sample stuck after some iterations?

Tags: go

I am trying to learn golang and i got a little piece of code that i do not understand why it gets stuck after some time.

```
package main

import "log"

func main() {
    deliveryChann := make(chan bool, 10000)

    go func() {
        for {
            deliveryChann <- true
            log.Println("Sent")
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-deliveryChann:
                log.Println("received")
            }
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-deliveryChann:
                log.Println("received")
            }
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-deliveryChann:
                log.Println("received")
            }
        }
    }()

    for {
    }
}
```

An basic start on how to investigate would suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main goroutine (running the `for {}` loop) is hogging the thread, and none of the other goroutines are able to execute because of it. If you change the end of your `main` function to:

```
for {
    runtime.Gosched()
}
```

then the thread will be released and another goroutine made active.

> `func Gosched()`
>
> Gosched yields the processor, allowing other goroutines to run. It does not suspend the current goroutine, so execution resumes automatically.

-- https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Gosched

Comment: And the problem here - that shouldn't happen if `GOMAXRPOCS` is bigger than 1. `for {}` will lock only one thread, other goroutines can be scheduled on other threads. But for some reason that doesn't happen

Comment: @creker - Yes, I wondered the same. I'm currently investigating why, as I am not sure of the cause.

Comment: and even more puzzling the fact that it runs for some time before deadlocking. I would understand if it would lock up immediately and that would be perfectly fine. It would perfectly fit the case of `for {}` locking the process before the runtime had any chance to spawn more worker threads.

Comment: Just for info: i am running the latest golang version, so gomaxprocs shouldnot be 1. I understand the issue with 1 cpu only (at least i do now), but for multiple cpus i am still at a loss.

Comment: The behaviour that we're interested in is defined by the scheduler. The scheduler will only switch a thread's context when the current goroutine (i) finishes, (ii) makes a blocking syscall, (ii) makes a blocking Go runtime call; or (iv) invokes another function (somethines) (ref: http://www.slideshare.net/matthewrdale/demystifying-the-go-scheduler). I'm still a bit new to Go, but I'm wondering: perhaps context switches in otherwise-independent threads are dependent on the running threads invoking the scheduler. Our main goroutine won't ever invoke it.

Comment: You're not the only one, you might be onto something here. Even this locks up https://play.golang.org/p/GqPG6NhDox I took go 1.2.2, the oldest one I could find, and it behaves differently - it locks up immediately in both cases. Maybe someone should post that as an issue for golang team to investigate. If it's not a bug maybe it would at least give us an explanation.

Comment: @icio, but here we have multiple goroutines and they do yield execution and allow the runtime to multiplex goroutines to other threads. In my case even main goroutine is no longer blocked but `for {}` in other one is still locking up the process.

Comment: I put `time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)` after `log.Println("Sent")` and now it no longer locks up. Or at least it runs much longer than before. If I put `time.Sleep(1 * time.Millisecond)` then it's locks up again. @JustMe, which OS did you test it on? I ran it on Windows 10.

Comment: @creker Mac OSX - El capitan 10.11.4 (15E65) here. Results are exactly the same as the ones you got.

Comment: `select {}` is preferred to `for {
    runtime.Gosched()
}`.  The select statement indicates that the goroutine is blocked until the program terminates.  The for loop spins asking the runtime to schedule another goroutine.

Comment: @JustMe, I created an issue https://github.com/golang/go/issues/15442 and now we have an explanation. Process hangs when GC is triggered. Process runs fine for a while, then GC is triggered. Because one of the goroutines hogs one of the threads it doesn't stop for GC which leads to entire process just hang as GC waits for goroutine to stop it's work. As I said in my last comment there, `runtime.GC()` will trigger the issue immediatelly.

Comment: Wonderful work, @creker -- thank you for the follow-up!

Comment: Super. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Order of execution of goroutings is undefined. Code gets stuck is legal. You can be more deterministic doing communication with `main()`. For example place

```
for {
   deliveryChann <- true
   log.Println("Sent")
}
```

`in main()` instead of `go func()`

Comment: Why would the order of operations matter? The channel is opened before any other routine runs. running latest version of go, so there is no issue with the number of cpus. (would love to understand how this happens).

Comment: Maybe an example batter explain what I mean http://play.golang.org/p/lrbs5NCEck . And this is expected behaviour.